# Unable to access a list of strings generated dynamically

Tags: string, flutter, dart, textfield

I generated a list of strings dynamically.
/

```
/I declared a list of strings and generated it using the length of my product.
late final List<String> recovered; 

//the length of the products is 3
recovered = List.generate(products.length, (index) => ""));
```

//I assigned the list generated to the onChanged method inside my TextField.

```
 TextField(
             onChanged: (value) {
             recovered[index] =
             value;
             log("the value is $value");
              setState(() {});
               },
                                    
              }),
```

I want to get each String generated and assigned to a map dynamically. Like this:
{"product": "Noodles", "recovered": "2"} //recovered is the string from the text field, the product is gotten from the list of products.
I can't use recovered[index] because it returns the string at the first index only. I can't do this recovered[1] because since the string is generated dynamically, I can't get each index.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution that works.

```
 List<Map> mapList = []; //Create a list of map
 var myproduct = {}; //a map that will take the product and the recovered.
```

Then assigned the myproduct to the list of map (mapList) inside the TextField.

```
 TextField(
    onChanged: (value) {
    recovered[index] =
    value;
 myproduct = {
 "product": products[index]['product'],                                                                                                                "quantity_delivered": value
};                                                                mapList.add(myproduct);
}),
```